# How to expose entities to a web project without adding a reference to the project that contains the full EntityFramework model?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, web-applications

I'm facing this problem with EntityFramework 5 (VS 2012). I have the following projects in my solution:

**I'm using database first and the designer**

1. Data. Where my entities model and entities are.
2. Security. Where the business logic for security is.
3. Web. The web UI

*Security* has a reference to *Data* so it can use the model and entities to retrieve data from the database. In *Security* I have a method the returns a list of *MenuOptions* (this is an entity in the project Data) to the UI (Web project). In the Web project I then want to iterate the list of *MenuOptions* to build a menu. The problem is that I don't want to add a reference to *Data* in my *Web* project just to be able to have access to the entities. Then, how can I make the entities in *Data* visible to *Web* without adding a reference to the full project? (I only want the entities to be accessible to the UI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the entities in a dll (or project) put your DbContext inherited class and entities mapping configuration in another.
This way you can distribute your entities dll in different projects without sharing DB access items.

Comment: Thanks, Arturo. If I do that, how do I configure my project with the DbContext so it knows that the entities are now in separate project? So when I add a new entity via the model designer, it knows that the entity class has to be placed in the separate project?

Comment: Your Data project (DbContext and mapping config) should reference your Entities project (dll).

Your Security project references both Data and Entities projects.

Comment: Even though the answer somehow guided me to the correct solution, I wanted to leave here the URL of the post that gave me the necessary steps to actually do the separation I needed: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/133689/How-to-Separate-Self-Tracking-Entities-to-Their-Ow